# Roles.IsUserInRole() : The name IsUserInRole does not exist in current context in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc4 to create authentication and authorization application ,and i have created a common login page for all users in different roles(authentication and authorization is based on role),it should ask for username and password and when we click on login button it should check the user's role in database,and i am checking that as in below code

But here its not entering in the if part,and also i have checked using add watch so it say's: IsUserInRole -The name 'IsUserInRole' does not exist in the current context

I am using simple membership provider and want to built application using built-in methods and i have configured all in web.config

I am not able to figure whats the problem,i have read/searched many articles,any help would be greatly appreciated, pls help me.

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName,"Admin")) 
{
  RedirectToAction("Admin","Home");
}
```

Comment: Are using this feature in another library? you should reference to `System.Web.dll` assembly.

Comment: System.Web.dll already added

Answer (score 2):

IsUserInRole sits in the `System.Web.Security` namespace and you'll have to reference System.Web.dll to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx

Comment: @codemaniac143 Did you read http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: yes i read. and now i am trying to use Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name),so even for this it says:The GetRolesForUser is does not exist  in the current context.so all this methods are not working in my login controller,right?

Comment: <roleManager  enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add  name="simple" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" applicationName="AA"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="simple" >
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="simple" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" applicationName="AA" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

Comment: I have added role in wepages_Roles table using one of the built in method Roles.CreateRole(),i have written the code for the same in global.asx,their this methods are working fine,then why not in login controller,whats wrong??!!..pls help

Comment: Not sure about this ... tried google and found the following hits, maybe you read them, maybe you didn't, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257232/role-based-authentication-in-the-new-mvc-4-internet-template-using-simplemembers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527152/how-exactly-do-i-use-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4, http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/, http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/24/perils-of-the-mvc4-accountcontroller.aspx

Comment: thanks @Erwin,i have gone through all this links before,but didnt work

Comment: If you debug, and look at the Roles is the Provider of type WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider?

Comment: if i got you right you mean Roles in itself is different provider and not of the type simpleroleprovider,even i think yes.but i tried creating object of SimpleRoleProvider and invoking method r.IsInRole,for that also it says IsInRole does not exist in current context

Comment: I mean Roles.Provider.

Comment: If i am using Roles.Provider..it says the name Provider does not exist in current context

Comment: In debug, what type is Roles? System.Web.Security.Roles?

Comment: Did you check out this link: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.be/2013/02/aspnet-mvc-4-membership-users-passwords.html

Comment: thanks,but after checking this still the condition is same and where u would write all this code to check the user's role???,may be i am making some mistakes

Comment: I tried,i am trying,but my problem is not yet solved,somebody pls help

Comment: Try starting from a clean Internet MVC 4 Application and put something like if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")) {} in your Login (post), check the type of Roles and Roles.Provider.

Comment: ,i created a new application and tried what you said,still same problem with IsUserInrole

Comment: Strange, when I create a new Internet MVS 4 app, the Roles is of type System.Web.Security.Roles and the Provider is of type WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider. I haven't changed anything to the project except for adding the if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")) {} in my Login (post).

Comment: Yes, as I explained in the previous comment.

Comment: can you pls share your web.config lines

Comment: That was my point, when you create a new MVC 4 app, there is nothing in the config about membership and rolemanager. SimpleRoleProvider is the default, there is a InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute that initializes your database connection (DefaultConnection).

Comment: Is their anyone ,who can help me to get out of the problem,i have spent much time on solving the problem,but i am not able to get out of it

Comment: ,can u pls tell ,exactly what you did

Comment: I made a new project, MVC 4, chose the internet template, added connectionstring for the DefaultConnection in the web.config and pointed it to a local SQLExpress Sql instance.

Comment: i want to hide some action methods in UI to some users based on their roles,how to do that????